# How to Measure PWM or Pulse Time using Microcontroller?

Tags: io, microcontroller

I am trying to figure out how long each pulse is using an IR sensor. It is connected to my current microcontroller (Basys MX3) but I am not sure how to read the total time for a pulse.

I have already initialized a digital input to read the pulse from the IR sensor but I am not sure how to capture the data that I need. I know I need to set it using PORTDbits.RD10 (reads value on pin) but is there a way I can set this to read a total pulse? I know the total pulse starts when it goes from low to high and ends when it goes from low to high again, but I am not sure how to read this.

Answer (score 2):

Your microcontroller is actually a PIC32MX370F512L. If you want to catch the rising and falling edge of the pulse, you can do so using change notification interrupts ([see example 12-1 here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/61120d.pdf)). As far as measuring the time between the rising and falling edges, you can use a hardware timer that is started and stopped based on the change notification interrupts. You'll be limited by the resolution that your hardware is actually capable of. Hopefully it's good enough. A better option would be to use a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.